# Отправление данных через глобальную сеть (нужны объяснения) - C++

Tags: сеть, winsock

Начал разбираться с сокетами winsocks. Написал прогу, которая по локальному адресу принимает и отправляет на один и тот же комп сообщения. Так вот
ведь по этому локальному адресу нельзя подключиться с другого компа. Я пытался в функции bind() передавать глобальный ip адресс, но он выдавал ошибку.

Так вот, как вообще реализовать так, что бы мой комп у меня был сервером, и к нему можно было подключаться с разных, не локальных компьютеров ?

Comment: локальный адрес - это 127.0.0.1 ? 

Но если хочется совсем с любым, то тут нужно, что бы у Вас был выделенный IP или хотя бы проброшен порт. Иначе задача стает малось нетревиальной.

Comment: Под локальным адресом может подразумеваться и 192.168.0.1/19, для этого никакого выделенного IP не нужно.

Comment: Покажите ваш нерабочий код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нулевую очередь - вам нужна книга Снейдера [Эффективное программирование TCP/IP](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/126048/)

В первую очередь, нужно определиться, как ваш компьютер соединен с интернетом. Редко какой домашний пользователь может похвастаться прямым IP из интернета - БЕЛЫМ IP. К белым относятся адреса, не являющиеся [частными](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81).

Узнать легко - зайдите на 2IP.RU или схожий сервис, и посмотрите, что он пишет про ваше подключение.

Если у вас белый IP, и между вашим компьютером и интернетом роутера нет - все тривиально - открываете сокет и работаете.

Если же есть какой-то роутер, то этот роутер, скорее всего - NAT. Тогда нужны средства обхода NAT.

Если вы владелец роутера, его нужно настроить - это называется [PortForwarding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81).

Если же нет, остается использовать техники обхода NAT, вроде ICE и STUN.

Также, существует возможность IP соединения через оверлейные сети - tor, [tox](https://github.com/gjedeer/tuntox) и так далее.

Comment: Для соединения с адресов `192.168.0.1/19` - зачем нужен "белый ip"?

Comment: @PinkTux судя по последнему абзацу, автор желает доступ из глобальной сети.

Comment: ну, для обучения и отладки примеров вполе сгодится :) Настройка доступа - это уже совсем другое, особого отношения к принципам программирования клиент-серверных штук не имеющее на этом этапе.

Comment: @PinkTux локальная сеть - вторая по идеальности среда передачи данных, после локалхоста. Практика показывает, что код, написанный для локалхоста, на вебе может творить чудеса.

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать

Comment: Я слабо понимаю что такое "код написанный для локалхоста". Там что - функции какие-то другие, библиотеки? Если же речь о проблемах, которые практически не встречаются в локалке, то не надо грузить человека лишними сущностями раньше времени. Он ещё ходить не умеет, а ему уже про особенности расстановки барьеров на дистанции 400 метров рассказывают...

Comment: @Pink Tux  "груз" в виде замечательного букваря за авторством Снейдера я уже выдал. Вопрошающему достаточно.